# Weighted overlay in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to weghted overlay in Google Earth Engine I want to overlay PDSI, SPI and SMI applying weights for each parameter.

This is how I am going to overlay them:

```
var overlay = spi.add(smi.add(pdsi))
```

How do I apply weighted overlay?

Comment: Can you specify your question please: How exactly do you want to apply weighted overlay? Using one fixed weight per layer? Do you need to re-organize your layers into categories, and if yes how? Is [this](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-weighted-overlay-works.htm) a conceptual example of want you want to do, and how would you modify it to your specific application?

Comment: I do this based on AHP. Each layer has a specific weight. I want to apply weight to each parameter then overlay together to create a new image. ex: SPI * 0.25,   PDSI*0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GEE's `ee.Image.expression()` function for more complex mathematical operations like both addition and multiplication as in your case (more info e.g. [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_math#expressions) and [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-expression)). As it works on an `ee.Image`, you need to combine your layers into one at first using `ee.Image.addBands()`.

Example code (factors need to be adjsted accordingly):

```
var image = spi.addBands(smi).addBands(pdsi)
var overlay = image.expression(
    '2 * spi + 5 * smi + 1.5 * pdsi', {
      'SPI': image.select('spi'),
      'SMI': image.select('smi'),
      'PDSI': image.select('pdsi')
});
```